# drawing a tail for a speech bubble in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics

I need to implement a speech bubble. I managed to get the main oval bubble (even the jagged shapes). Now I am trying to get the tail part. The tail should be

```
1. Resizable (extend/ rotate around the bubble)
2. When the bubble is dragged, the tail and bubble should move together (obviously).
3. The border where tail and bubble intersect should be clear.
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260701/iphone-how-do-i-make-two-connected-line-to-follow-to-the-position), but I am at a step before that. Some guidance on how to get to that level, where I have a triangle tail inside the ellipse would be very helpful.( I already have the ellipse with drawrect method which i followed from a tutorial).

Do I need another custom UIView subclass for the tail alone? Also, down the lane, I would like to have different styles for the tail (triangle, array of  circles as in a thought bubble, etc)
[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help if we could see your current code.

Comment: Is that a mockup or your current output?

Comment: @MarceloCantos I will post the code soon. It is in a messed up shape, with lot of test code. Let me clean it up. And By simply asking the question ( and further reading), I got some ideas myself so I will try those out before bugging you guys. :)

Comment: @PeterHosey The image above is a mockup. what I want in the end. But I have something close to that minus the tail part. I am trying some ideas, and will update soon. Thanks again :)

Comment: @aVC, can you please post the code which will be useful to me.

Comment: @Pallavi That was a long time back, and I was getting started with app programming, but did not progress much. Never got this done. Sorry:(